# JQuery: Click to Hide DIV, how can I make one function to click and hide individual divs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have multiple divs like setted up below. I want **1 (one)** JQuery function that onclick of ahref (.hide), Hide the data inside the `<div class="data">`.

1. This should be 1 function that can hide multiple DIV's 
2. An explanation would be great if using the jquery `this` selector, I suspect this is what I need.
3.Keep it simple!
4. Also a nice sliding toggle effect would be great, to slide up and down on click.

I attempted this, but I had to make different jquery code for each div, which is... long..

**Thanks for any help!! and hopefully correct answers!!**

```
<div id="uniqueDiv1" class="frame">
    <a href="#" class="hide">Hide</a> // On click of this Div
        <div class="data">
            <pre>data</pre>           // Hide This Div or Data
        </pre>
</div>

<div id="uniqueDiv2" class="frame">
    <a href="#" class="hide">Hide</a> // On click of this Div
        <div class="data">
            <pre>data</pre>           // Hide This Div or Data
        </pre>
</div>


<remember> I want 1 simple Jquery DOM function for all Multiple Divs </remember>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could it like this:

```
$('div.frame a.hide').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).next('div.data').toggle(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/QbDMs/

- The `$('div.frame a.hide')` selects all the "hide" links.
- The `e.preventDefault();` prevents the default link action
- The `$(this).next('div.data').toggle();` selects the next div with `class="data"` and toggles its visibility

**edit** 
 - You didn't mention this, but if you want to toggle the text on the button as well, you could add:

```
if ($(this).text()=='Show'){
     $(this).text('Hide');   
    }else{
     $(this).text('Show');   
}
```

making the final code look like:

```
$('div.frame a.hide').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var div =$(this).next('div.data').slideToggle(); 
    if ($(this).text()=='Show'){
     $(this).text('Hide');   
    }else{
     $(this).text('Show');   
    }
});
```

Comment: This works perfect, even with the Hide and Show text, but If I have <pre> </pre> tags inside div.data, the function doesnt work, any idea's for a workaround?

Comment: @PHP_Guy It does work. I noticed the markup you provided closed 2 `</pre>` tags instead of `</pre></div>` which could have been the problem. I fixed them in my example link, should be working as expected now.

Comment: Hi, I made a type in the question, my code has the correct tags. It works if i dont use no effects, ie: var div...... toggle(); but when I use slideToggle(), or fadeToggle(), it animates away, but the text doesnt change, it just shows "hide". any ideas?

Comment: @PHP_Guy I've updated my answer/link. When you use slideToggle() it changes the opacity in an animation and as such doesn't directly become hidden. So when the script checks whether it's hidden, it isn't yet. Changed the condition to check its current text instead.

Comment: Thanks so much! works perfect! and nice and simple and well explained,

Answer (score 4):

```
$("a.hide").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().find(".data").slideToggle();
});
```

This should work.  `this` refers to the item clicked. It simply finds the `.data` within the parent div and `slideToggle`s it.

fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/yJfbP/

NOTE: Your html in your post is malformed. You have `</pre>` where you should be ending a div.

Comment: @Fosco only with his malformed html.  See the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hide').click(function()) {
        $(this).next().hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".frame .hide").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var txt = $this.text();
    if(txt == "Hide"){
        $this.text("Show");
    } else {
        $this.text("Hide");
    }
    $this.next(".data").toggle();
});
```